# How to make a div move up and down like a floating baloon

Tags: jquery

**Overview**

I want a div to be moved up and down, slowly, looking like a baloon floating in the air.

**Findings**

I came up with this and note the external script attached to it : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FLMp8/1/)

**Issue**

One, it is not very smooth and it looks like breaking. Two, as you can see, the image looks like its being squashed when it moves up and down. How can I make it move smooth or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, then you can try:

```
   var baloon = $('#baloon');
   function runIt() {
       baloon.animate({top:'+=20'}, 1000);
       baloon.animate({top:'-=20'}, 1000, runIt);
   }

   runIt();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using css3 animations. You can look at some examples and tutorials here: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want more support then just browsers that support CSS3, try jQuery's slideUp animation: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this jQuery library

http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jqfloat/